# Flask-bcrypt hash result is not as expected

Tags: python, bcrypt

I have to implement security measures for the project of the course I am taking and I ran into something that I wasn't expecting.

First of all, I stored the password:

```
########################## Password hashing ############################
        # 1. Generate salt
        salt = os.urandom(32)
        salt = (binascii.hexlify(salt)).decode('utf-8')

        # 2. Append salt to the password
        password = data['password']
        password = password + salt
        # 3. Hash the password and storing
        password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(password).decode('utf-8')
        output_msg = database_helper.save_new_user(data['email'], password, data['firstname'], data['familyname'], data['gender'], data['city'], data['country'], salt)

        ########################################################################
```

This is the data that is saved in the database:

```
salt2@salt.com|$2b$12$WJx.XLYk/8Zx4HdDnPqxK.0RiZ6QR8rQEpZrw7jBpJRFUZ2sfBWyW|salt2|sal|male|link |swe|b5e333e0bae505d4fae6d9b993bcdcfd6964e480ce4dc1b5fd6b13c034d23bb8
```

For the password validation, I do the following:

```
########################### Password validation ############################
# 1. Retrive user's salt from the database
authentication_data = database_helper.get_users_salt(email)

# 2. Append salt to the inputed password and hash it
inputed_password = inputed_password + authentication_data['salt']
inputed_password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(inputed_password).decode('utf-8')


# 3. Compare the hash generated from the inputed password with the one in
#    the database
boolean_success = database_helper.check_user_password(email, inputed_password)

############################################################################
```

And getting the salt from the database show as result this, which is what I stored:

```
b5e333e0bae505d4fae6d9b993bcdcfd6964e480ce4dc1b5fd6b13c034d23bb8
```

And hashing the inputed_password with the salt shows as a result this:

```
$2b$12$yEE.OX5IFyIXTK4x3XOBbO4Ospm2hcCz9FCmjzEn3tC5DNg9crtxy
```

In a nutshell, why is showing different hashing results?

Comment: The code seems simple enough and fine. Make sure the salt is really the same and doesn't have a line break at the end. Make sure the password is really the same too. Maybe you have two users with the same email in your database?

Comment: What does the function `database_helper.check_user_password` do? Is it from some library or if your code, could you post it?

Comment: My database has unique mails, and check_user_password was working fine before implementing the security retrains, it compares the inputted password with the stored one.

Comment: Alright but the code seems fine so maybe the problem is with this function?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer what is wrong with your code, since I cannot see all of it. But, for what it's worth, this is what I use for creating and validating passwords using `bcrypt`:

**Create:**

```
# password entered by user
hashed = bcrypt.hashpw(password.encode('utf-8'), bcrypt.gensalt())
hashed_str = hashed.decode('ascii')
# store out hashed_str for user
```

**Validate:**

```
# retrieve hashed_str for user
# password entered by user
valid =  bcrypt.checkpw(password.encode('utf-8'), hashed_str.encode('ascii'))
```

**Note**

`bcrypt` only handles passwords up to 72 bytes, any additional characters being ignored. So if you allow passwords that might encode to longer than 72 bytes, you might want to use the following code:

**Create:**

```
# password entered by user
password_bytes = password.encode('utf-8')
if len(password_bytes) > 72:
    password_bytes = base64.b64encode(hashlib.sha256(password_bytes).digest())
hashed = bcrypt.hashpw(password_bytes, bcrypt.gensalt())
hashed_str = hashed.decode('ascii')
# store out hashed_str for user
```

**Validate:**

```
# retrieve hashed_str for user from database
# password entered by user
password_bytes = password.encode('utf-8')
if len(password_bytes) > 72:
    password_bytes = base64.b64encode(hashlib.sha256(password_bytes).digest())
valid =  bcrypt.checkpw(password_bytes, hashed_str.encode('ascii'))
```